# Enumerate thru items in XML feed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have a collection view that shows the results of an XML feed.  It works great, but I need to save the results of the XML feed locally (if no internet connection available for example).

I know how to save the raw feed locally, but I think what I really need to be doing is **iterating thru the items in the XML feed and saving each as a NSData item**.

Is that the right way to think about it, or do you have any useful advice or tips?

```
- (void)startParsing
{
    NSXMLParser *xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss#sthash.TyhRD7Zy.dpuf"]];
    [xmlparser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlparser parse];
    if (_marrXMLDataCollection.count != 0) {
        // Save XML to NSData items in background?

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}
```

*Here's an example of what the feed looks like, and I have this stored in the Documents directory as `localdata.plist` too:*

```
(
        {
        link = "\nhttp://www.apple.com/pr/library/2016/04/26Apple-Reports-Second-Quarter-Results.html?sr=hotnews.rss";
        pubDate = "\nTue, 26 Apr 2016 14:44:21 PDT";
        title = "\nApple Reports Second Quarter Results";
    },
        {
        link = "\nhttp://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/in-action/trim-editing/?sr=hotnews.rss";
        pubDate = "\nWed, 20 Apr 2016 10:05:59 PDT";
        title = "\n\nFinal Cut Pro X helps small company delight world\U2019s biggest clients";
    },
        {
        link = "\nhttp://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/?sr=hotnews.rss";
        pubDate = "\nMon, 21 Mar 2016 12:00:03 PDT";
        title = "\n\nApple Introduces 9.7-inch iPad Pro";
    },
        {
        link = "\nhttp://www.apple.com/iphone-se/?sr=hotnews.rss";
        pubDate = "\nMon, 21 Mar 2016 11:58:09 PDT";
        title = "\n\nApple Introduces iPhone SE \U2014 the Most Powerful Phone with a 4-inch Display";
    },
```

Comment: Why not just save the XML?

Comment: @Wain You're saying save the XML in a property list, or something different? In that case, I wasn't sure how well that would work because there will end up being photos in the feed too eventually and I would need to turn those into NSData items instead/additionally right?

Comment: how would the photos be in the XML? base64 encoded strings?

Comment: @Wain Yep, photos would be base64 encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just save the XML directly to a file, either as binary data or text. You don't need to unpack it and convert it to anything. Later you can then load the fine and re-run your parsing code. This is the least code option. It's more runtime costly but unless your XML file is rather large you won't notice the difference.

If you want to save the processed content then your XML should be getting turned into an array of model objects and you can implement `NSCoding` on those model objects to allow you to archive them to disk. This should be more runtime efficient but is also more code.

Comment: Awesome.  I'll give you the bounty in 11 hours when it lets me.

Comment: Can I ask you a quick question, if the photos are not base64 encoded strings would the solution be a lot different?

Comment: generally in that case the feed would contain something like links to download the images, so the XML feed wouldn't contain the actual image. as such it wouldn't change your storage much, in either case, dependent on when you download the images. you'd likely use a separate image caching system and keep it away from the XML.

Comment: Right like if the image was stored in a URL in the XML feed, so I'd need to iterate thru the feed, and find those URLs and turn them into NSData and store them locally separately, since I'm trying to get it to where if there is no internet connection everything still shows up?

Comment: yeah, but i'd use something like SDWebImage rather than write that yourself

Comment: I see. Makes sense.  Thanks!!